# copying all properties of one pojo to another in java?

Tags: java, java-ee-6

I have below POJO of some third party jar which we cannot expose to our clients directly.

**ThirdPartyPojo.java**

```
public class ThirdPartyPojo implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String name;
    private String ssid;
    private Integer id;

    //public setters and getters

}
```

Above class is part of third party jar which we are using as below.

```
ThirdPartyPojo result = someDao.getData(String id);
```

Now our plan is as `ThirdPartyPojo` is part of third party jar, we cannot send `ThirdPartyPojo` result type directly to clients. we want to create our own pojo which will have same properties as `ThirdPartyPojo.java` class. we have to set the data from ThirdPartyPojo.java to `OurOwnPojo.java` and return it as below.

```
public OurOwnPojo getData(String id){

    ThirdPartyPojo result = someDao.getData(String id)

    OurOwnPojo response = new OurOwnPojo(result);

    return response;

    //Now we have to populate above `result` into **OurOwnPojo** and return the same.

}
```

Now I want to know if there is a best way to have same properties in `OurOwnPojo.java` as `ThirdPartyPojo.java` and populate the data from `ThirdPartyPojo.java` to `OurOwnPojo.java` and return the same?

```
public class OurOwnPojo implements java.io.Serializable {

    private ThirdPartyPojo pojo;

    public OurOwnPojo(ThirdPartyPojo pojo){

         this.pojo = pojo
    }


    //Now here i need to have same setter and getters as in ThirdPartyPojo.java

    //i can get data for getters from **pojo**

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: extend ThirdPartyPojo class into your OurOwnPojo class

Answer (score 18):

Probably you are searching `Apache Commons` [BeanUtils.copyProperties](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html).

```
public OurOwnPojo getData(String id){

  ThirdPartyPojo result = someDao.getData(String id);
  OurOwnPojo myPojo=new OurOwnPojo();

  BeanUtils.copyProperties(myPojo, result);
         //This will copy all properties from thirdParty POJO

  return myPojo;
}
```

Comment: nice, I knew it but forgot about it :D

Answer (score 2):

org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils is better than apache aone:

```
Task subTask = new Task();
org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(subTaskInfo.getTask(), subTask);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't misjudge origin and destination pojos:

```
try {

  BeanUtils.copyProperties(new DestinationPojo(), originPojo);

} catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```